# Sql tuning using execution plan

Tags: sql-tuning

I have a scenario where the sql query(In oracle 11G environment which encapsulated in proc) is taking long time than usual time as there is no memory/ network/query issue else there will not be any additional volume of records.

In this scenario, i'd like to check whether the execution plan got changed or not? can you assist me how to check the execution plan(ideal tool to check) and how to bring back to the old execution plan of that query?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are talking about the normal sql code used inside an procedure.
There are three options to check the execution plan, 
a. set autotrace traceonly explan;
b. using tkprof
c. sql/developer tool, you will see an icon on the menu, an Icon next to explain plan.

If you details about a or b, please do let me know, will give you some samples.

To use an old plan, you should have saved it earlier, have you saved it ?, you can try to seach for the same using plan_table.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle DB you can use the below query to check the SQL execution plan, you can check if your SQL is going through an indexing or full table scan.

```
EXPLAIN PLAN FOR SELECT * from TABLE_NAME where some_coloumn='PUT FILTER HERE';
SELECT PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY());
```